# Question on half yearly compound interest system.

Tags: arithmetic

$X$ borrowed Rs.$150000$ from $Y$ at the rate of $21$ percent per year. At the end of $15$ months, how much compound interest should $X$ pay compounded half yearly?

My Attempt.

I solved it using the formula ;
$$C.I=P[(1+\frac {R}{200})^{2T} (1+\frac {MR}{1200})-1]$$.
Where, T=1 year and M=3months.

I got the answer as $C.I=Rs. 42759.3219$ but the answer given in my book is $Rs. 49500$?

How did this happen? Please help me to get the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Half yearly compound interest system](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010318/half-yearly-compound-interest-system)

Comment: @Claude, But there are no any answers and comments in that post.

Comment: The reason for no answer is that there must be a typo. I have the same result like you. I tried different ways of calculation but all my results were (very) close to your result.

Comment: @Callculus, I just wanted to confirm that is the formula that I used correct? And is T=1 year and M=3 months or not?

Comment: I fully agree to your thoughts and your calculation. But there is a small chance that I misinterpret the exercise.

Comment: @Callculus,  what is your misinterpretation?

Comment: @user354073 I don´t know if I misinterpret something, but maybe I do. If I do not then you´re right. Here on MSE there are many users who know how to deal with such exercises. Since you haven´t got an answer it is likely that there is a typo in your exercise.

Comment: @callculus,  But someone should specify the typo, too? then

Comment: @user354073 I changed some (many) values (interest rate, duration) but I never got the given result. Often it is very hard to identify typos. You have to wait until someone find a solution or not.